# How come I can't bind this to JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    $("input").bind("keyup",function(e1){
                if(e1.keyCode==13){   
                 return false;        
                  }
            });
```

I want to return false everytime someone pushes "enter" inside one of my text boxes.

Comment: why do you want to return false??? just don't handle enter scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k i tried it out this one works

```
$("textarea").bind("keypress", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) return false;
    });
```

try with keycode 13 too

Comment: when will we need this type of situation??

Comment: what do i know he asked for it ofc you can change textarea to anything you want

Answer (score -1):

See [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Your answer:

```
$('input').submit(function() {
  return false;
});
```

Comment: The question is about stopping the enter key from submitting a form, not stopping a form form being submitted altogether, and this code is useless — there is no submit event for input elements (as the page you link to says).